# How can I build the boost libraries 1_72_0 on a windows host for a linux target?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, boost, b2

Trying to build the boost libraries, I followed the steps:

1. open cmd in **boost_1_72_0** folder
2. ***bootstrap.bat** gcc*
3. set cfalgs, cxxflags and linker flags to use the sysroot folder that came with the compiler:

***cflags**="-std=c11 -O2 --sysroot=C:\toolchain\sysroot-newlib-arm-2019.01-aarch64-elf -Wall -O0 -std=c11 -D_GLIBC_USE_NANOSLEEP -DLINUX -std=c11 -g"*

***cxxflags**="-std=c++11 -O2 --sysroot=C:\toolchain\sysroot-newlib-arm-2019.01-aarch64-elf -Wall -O0 -std=c++11 -static-libstdc++ -D_GLIBCXX_USE_NANOSLEEP -DLINUX -std=c++11 -g"*

***linkerflags**="--sysroot=C:\toolchain\sysroot-newlib-arm-2019.01-aarch64-elf"*

4. run the b2 command with the following options:

   ***.\b2.exe** -d+3 --debug-configuration target-os=linux toolset=gcc-aarch64 architecture=arm address-model=64 cflags="%cflags%" cxxflags="%cxxflags%"  linkflags="%linkerflags%" --with-iostreams --with-filesystem --with-regex --with-locale --with-headers --with-date_time --with-random --with-thread --with-timer --with-system -q threading=multi variant=release link=static --prefix=../boost-test/ install*

I used the 8.2-2019.01, AArch64 ELF bare-metal target (aarch64-elf), compiler from [this website](https://developer.arm.com/downloads/-/gnu-a).

After running the b2 command, I get the following message: "**...failed updating 8 targets...**" and the **boost-test/lib folder is empty**.
Do you have any idea what might be the problem?

Comment: Are you sure you want a bare metal target? I can imagine filesystem/threading/... depends on an OS. Btw. you are writing you want a linux target but use a bare-metal target compiler.

Comment: @akirahinoshiro I am not sure what bare metal means, can you explain me please? I know that it somehow doesn't depend on the OS, but I it is not very clear to me. Also, what I know is that I have to cross-compile the boost libraries on windows for a linux aarch64 target using that version of the compiler. I had only the bare metal and linux options, no compiler version for windows download, that is why I chose bare metal.

Comment: "In computer science, bare machine (or bare metal) refers to a computer executing instructions directly on logic hardware without an intervening operating system." this sentence can be found on Wikipedia. What I think you want is Windows host and Linux target.

Comment: @akirahinoshiro Thank you! Yes, I need Windows host for Linux target, but unfortunately, I don't think that the version of the compiler that I have to use is available in this format, so I will try to find another one.